# How to to turn round robin word problem into formal argument?

Tags: proof-verification, graph-theory, directed-graphs

A round-robin tournament consists of $n$ players and all possible games between any two players. Each game can result in win or loss of a player but no draws are allowed. A champion is a player $A$ such that for every other player $B$ either $A$ beats $B$ (in the game between A and B ) or there is a player $C$ such that $A$ beats $C$ who, in turn, beats $B$.

1.)Show that every tournament with at least two players has a champion.

2.)Can you prove that there is more than one champion?

So part 1 seems obvious since there can be no draw between any two players and therefore one of the players must win resulting in a champion

For part 2, if $A$ beats $B$, $B$ beats $C$, and $C$ beats $A$ in a tournament then all three would be considered champions.

Is there something I'm missing? I do not feel I am doing this right because the answers seem too straightforward. Also, how can I convey my answers properly? I have only ever worked with formal proofs of short propositions and never a word problem like this.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Things that are straightforward are things that you understand. Good work.

Comment: Thanks mate. But would you consider my answer to part two a "proof"?

Comment: Is the wording you used in part two exactly the same as what was asked? Because surely there *can* be more than one champion, but there need not be.

Comment: @The Count Yes, exact wording.

Comment: I disagree with the first comment, I don't believe that the given justification for part 1 is enough. I have detailed this in my answer.

Comment: For 2 you have shown that there can be more than one champion, but you have not shown that there must be more than one.  The way the question is stated you are asked to show there must be more than one.  If the players are linearly ranked and each defeats all the ones below itself there is only one champion.

Comment: @Ross Milikan I would disagree. I am not seeing where the question states there must be more than one champion, only that you can prove that there could be more than one champion. Your reasoning makes sense but there is no part of the question that states the players are linearly ranked. Could you elaborate more on your argument?

Comment: The confusion comes from the phrasing of the question in part $2$. The phrase "there is" generally is not the same as "there can be" or "there is a situation where". @RossMillikan is interpreting this as "there must be" which is how I interpret the question as well. However, as Ross demonstrates, there are situations where "there are not" multiple champions, particularly when the players are linearly ranked. From this perspective, the question seems to be asking you to prove something that is not true. However, if you interpret "there is" as "there can be", then your justification is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bit more subtelty to this problem because of the fact that this is not a transitive tournament i.e. just because $A$ beats $B$ and $B$ beats $C$, that doesn't mean that $A$ beats $C$.

$\textbf{1)}$ Your justification is not enough. It is not an obvious fact because of the subtlety here: "or there is a player C such that A beats C who, in turn, beats B". A champion need not win every game (and in many cases will not have won every game, even if there is only one single champion!).

Proof by induction. Let $P(n)$ be the proposition that a tournament with $n$ players must have a champion.

Base Case: $(P(2))$ Suppose there is a tournament with two players. Since at least the players must play one another, and there can be no tie, then the winning player must be the champion, since he has beat every other player. So $P(2)$ is true.

Inductive Step: Suppose that $P(n)$ is true. Consider $P(n+1)$. For a tournament with $(n+1)$ players, select any $n$ players. By our hypothesis, this set of players must have a champion, lets call him $A$. Consider the other $n$ players besides $A$. By our hypothesis, this set of players must also have a champion, lets call him $B$. Since $A$ and $B$ play each other, then if $B$ beats $A$, then $B$ is the champion. Otherwise $A$ is the champion. So $P(n+1)$ is true. QED

$\textbf{2)}$ Your justification is enough. This is the simplest example. As mentioned in the comments, there need not be multiple champions, but there certainly could be.

Comment: Thanks Joey. for number 1) are you expanding upon the part of the proposition that states "show that every tournament" and not just the one tournament with 2 players? If so, it's a good answer and seems to be what I was missing.

Comment: @bluesky11 Yes, in part 1 of my answer, I give a complete inductive solution for "show that every tournament with at least two players has a champion".

Comment: thanks, I will most likely accept your answer after I have given some more time to debate part 2. I agree with your argument that my justification is enough. However, I would like to be sure.